# how to convert the small image into big images without affect the resolution in Photoshop?

Tags: plugins, image-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs4

I am using Photoshop CS6. 
I have  images in small sizes(3.5mm X 3.5mm). 
I enlarge the image size in(10cm X 8 cm). 
Then the image quality are going low.. 
SO how to enlarge the images without affect the resolution. 
BiCubic Smoother is not satisfied me..

Is there any way to resize images to high resolutions without losing pixels.

Comment: mm and cm makes no sense with images on a video device/monitor. What is the original *pixel* size?

Comment: ok you take to convert the 100px X 150px into 600px x 750px

Comment: You can't fabricate image quality that isn't there.

Comment: cannot-the word is not in my dictionary... I can do. then i will tell how do i do.

Comment: When you're done with this project, maybe you can tackle flying cars. We've been waiting for those for far too long.

Comment: ok i will try.. you will be finance for that project,

Comment: Well, you better get a new dictionary... Unlike flying cars, what you are asking for is incompatible with the laws of this universe.

Comment: Ok mr.jean-francois... Thank's For Your Idea...

Answer (score 4):

If you enlarge an image with a factor of 6:1 (as in this case) you will have an image missing 5/6 of information that need to be "filled" with constructed information by mathematical means. In most cases interpolation (bi-cubic or otherwise)  is used.

Unfortunately this will never result in anything sharp and high quality due to the nature of interpolating (basically averaging the constructed color points between the actual pixels). The picture will appear blurry no matter what you try to do in a case like this.

You can always throw a sharpening convolution on it, but the result will never be ideal.

For example, lets say I have a 2x1 pixel image that looks like this (enlarged for example):

[image: 2x1 pixels]

If I now want to enlarge this image using interpolation I will end up with an image containing information like this:

[image: Enlarged]

As you can see two points between the black and white needs to be reconstructed. As there is no way of knowing how these points would look like (as they never existed in the image in the first place) we need to guess how they would look like by averaging the black and white points.

[image: 4x1 pixels]

This will result in a "gray scale" that will result in the image looking blurry.

The more complex interpolation algorithms can make a better guess by using more points to get a Bezier approach for the non-existing points and so forth, but it will always be a good guess at best.

Now, this example uses 2:1 enlarging. You can probably by now imagine then how 6:1 scale will appear.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in this way. you will lose quality because your image and Photoshop are pixel based.
you can convert your picture to vector using softwares like corel draw.